# REST Service doesn't work after a simple change

Tags: java, json, rest

I follow this tutorial to learn some REST services and AJAX calls: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/

I changed this endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces("application/json")
public Product getProductInJSON() {

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("iPad 3");
    product.setQty(999);

    return product; 

}
```

to this one, in order to return the product in the jsonp format:

```
@GET
@Path("/get?callback={name}")
@Produces("application/javascript")
public String getProductInJSON(@PathParam("name") String callback){

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("iPad 3");
    product.setQty(999);

    String productString = callback + "({" + product.toString() + "})";

    return productString; 

}
```

with the toString() of product:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name:" + name + "," + "qty:" + qty;
}
```

But now, when I check ir the URI works in the browser, with:

> http://localhost:8080/restws/json/product/get?callback=process

i have this error message:

> HTTP ERROR: 404
>
> Could not find resource for relative : /json/product/get of full path:
>   http://localhost:8080/restws/json/product/get?callback=process
>
> RequestURI=/restws/json/product/get

Can somebody help me with understanding why it's giving me this error after this minor changing? Thanks

Comment: You're declaring your `callback` param to be called `name` in the URL with the annotation, isn't that the problem? Another one, although not related is that in the `toString()` method `name` should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: yes, you were right with the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query parameter isn't part of the @Path. You should handle them with [@QueryParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) as shown in the [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e253).