# Springboot :fullcalendar events.push doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I load all events on full-calender using Ajax , but problem events.push doesn't work

```
$(function() {
     var events = [];
        $.ajax({
         url: '/ajaxjson',
         Type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {

             $.map(data, function(r) {

                 alert(r.libelle);  //it's work


                 events.push({title: r.libelle,
                           start: r.date,
                            end: r.enddate});
             });

         },
     error: function (error) {
        alert('error :'+eval(error));
         //alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
     },
     });
```

but events.push  doesn't work

Comment: use ajax to render in a div the value of your events, and first create an html to render the component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax call to REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112672/jquery-ajax-call-to-rest-service)

Comment: @aepure I load all events on full-calender using Ajax , but problem events.push doesn't work

Comment: @kamkam - in the browser, open the developer's console (F12) and see if you get any errors. what are the errors?  What does 'data' contain (just print the JSON you get, use the Developer's console)