# How to pass a java variable to a different jsp page containing javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

my java class:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/front", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String onemethod(@RequestParam String name, Model model) { String str = "something";
 model.addAttribute("str", str); 
return "jsppage";
 }`

jsp page:

```
        var arrayCollection = ${str}
```

With this code, I'm getting 404 exception on Tomcat. I'm unable to send java variable to a different jsp page. Any help would be appreciated for this case.

Comment: It seems that you want to call a rest service from javascript. visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112672/jquery-ajax-call-to-rest-service

Comment: I put an ajax as you suggested, but data seem to be not going to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to wrap this up:

2 choices:

1. add variable to the model and access it directly in JSP
2. make it a rest method and call from ajax

Examples:

Ad.1.:

Controller

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@RequestMapping(value = "/front", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String onemethod(Model model) throws IOException, ParseException {
    String str = "something";
    model.addAttribute("str", str);
    return "jsppage";
}
```

JSP ("jsppage")

```
var test = '${str}';
```

Ad.2.:

Controller

```
// just to show JSP
@RequestMapping(value = "/front", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String onemethod() throws IOException, ParseException {
    return "jsppage";
}

// REST
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String secondmethod() {
    return "something";
}
```

JSP ("jsppage")

```
$.ajax({
    method : "get",
    url : "rest",
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

If you want to also send "name" parameter, add **@RequestParam String name** to the controller method and call ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method : "get",
    url : "rest",
    dataType : 'text',
    data : {"name" : "some name"},
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks.I did it. How would I retrieve it at javascript?

Comment: Ok, now your problems looks different, you have 2 choices here: return to the previous example with "var something = '${str}' and you should have your string "str" in JSP, or do things like you do now but add @ResponseBody to the controller method and send your "name" parameter in "data" attribute in ajax (or set it as @RequestParam(required=false) String name). Then you'll have whatever you have under the "jsppage" in javascript. You can also try changing "dataType" to text since you return a String.

Comment: I did as you said, with @responsebody I'm getting data at localhost. but it's not going to javascript. It seems something's wrong in my ajax. can you look at it?

Comment: Please look at my edit and check any of the two examples

Comment: I think I'll go with first one. It works fine with request param removed.

Comment: import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@RequestMapping(value = "/front", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String onemethod(@RequestParam String name, Model model) throws IOException, ParseException {
    String str = "something";
    model.addAttribute("str", str);
    return "jsppage";
}

Comment: with request param, added its not working fine for the first way.

Comment: I've modified my question. please look at it.

Comment: Of course, because then you need to provide it on initial GET, for example: localhost:8080/front?name=test, or make it "not required" by: **@RequestParam(required=false) String name**